# How to use a color as a placeholder in UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage

How can I use color as a placeholder in UIImage? For example I have an image like this:

[image]

And I want to change red to other image and receive something like this:

[image]

I thought about checking color of pixels and checking whether it's red and finding a frame, but maybe you know any better methods?

Comment: You can simply put the background color of your image to red.

Comment: What do you mean? I have to replace red color with an image

Comment: check if the image is nil, then replace the red color with an image

Comment: But the problem is that this green/blue(don't know exactly how to call this color) and red is in one UIImage, and I have to leave green/blue as it is and merge new uiimage into red color frame

Answer (score 0):

You need to take two `View`, one is `UIView` with a backgroundcolor of green(let us say), on that `UIView` you need to put your `UIImageView`, and you need to set the constraint according to that. Now set the background color of your `UIImageView` as red, and as per your requirement, check if the `UIImageView's` `image` is nil, if yes then you can add an image to your `UIImageView`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do like that. It looks easier than finding a red color frame and dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will create a `UIImage` from the specified color. You can call this method with `.red` to generate the placeholder image you want.

```
static func image(fromColor color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect)

    let img = renderer.image { ctx in
        ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        ctx.cgContext.fill(rect)
    }

    return img
}
```